# How to copy a line feature into a polygon personal geodatabase feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, convert, personal-geodatabase

I have a line shapefile with a proposed hiking trail.  I am trying to copy this feature into a larger geodatabase feature class.  The feature class is set to polygons.  Is there a way I can just convert a line to a polygon? or some way to get it into this polygon feature class.  It is just a single line, not a grid or parcel lines.  I'd like it to be a polygon that just looks like a line, just a few pixels wide.

Comment: You could use the [buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool on your line shapefile with a minimal *buffer_distance* value, this will convert your line to a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Use buffer tool ([Buffer in ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm), [Buffer in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html)). Example in ArcMap:

Input is your line shapefile. Output is a polygon in your database. Set the width of the buffer very small, in example below its 5 meters on each side of line = 10 meters total

[image: Buffer tool]
[image: Result]